# Display an array of 'double' numbers with unknown size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

**Update 1:** I need help with this the second part of this. I am asking the user to input numbers and to stop by using a zero. But then I want to display that code back. This is how far I got because when I want to display it it gives me different numbers. I'm ignoring user errors assuming when they input the first time it will be correct. But I do want them to input negative numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float data;
    int count=0;
    int*arr=new int[count];

    //get amount of numbers inputted 
    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n";
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n";
    cin>>data;
    for (; data != 0 ; ++count)
    {
        cin>>data;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    //display back data
    cout<<"The numbers enterd are: "<<endl; 
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**Update 2:**This code is part of a bigger project I'm working on. My professor is never going to see the code he just cares that it is working. The design of my code is not a priority in this case. Also I have never used `std::vector` before so I needed another way to do it. But this is what I did and it worked fine. I also commented off `delete []arr` because my code wouldn't run properly if I didn't do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 

    double data; 
    int count=0; 
    double *arr =new double[count]; 

    //get data 
    cout<<"Please enter floating point data."<<endl; 
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero)"<<endl; 
    do
    {
        cin>>arr[count]; 
        data = arr[count]; 

        count++; 

    }while(data != 0); 

    //display back data 
    cout<<"The numbers entered are: "<<endl; 
    for(int i=0; i<(count-1); i++) 
    { 
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    } 


    //delete []arr;  

 system ("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Well, (1) the input loop just overwrites the `data` variable repeatedly, (2) a raw array is bad in this context, use a `std:.vector`, (2) with `std::vector` you don't need to maintain a separate count since the `std::vector` does that for you, (4) the `system("pause")` is both non-portable, unnecessary and annoying, i.e. completely silly, (5) the `return 0;` is the default for `main`, but while some people choose to intentionally include it anyway, adding stuff for no particular reason is generally not a good idea.

Comment: (1) thank you I didn't see how it overwrote the data variable but I can see it know and I'll try to fix it, (2) this is code is for a bigger project and I've never learned std::vector (3) yes, i know system("pause") is silly and annoying but if I don't use it with compiler I use my program won't run (I have used compilers where I don't need it and I won't use it), (4) my professor requires me to use return 0 and I didn't know it doesn't have to be there so thank you again for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have C++ 11 or above, use auto

replace

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

with

```
for(auto v: arr){
    cout << v << endl;
}
```

Please remember, you'll need compiler supporting C++11 to use auto.

> If C++ < 11, Use std::for_each

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(float v){
    cout << v << endl;
}


int main ()
{
    float data;
    int count=0;
    std::vector<float> arr;

    //get amount of numbers inputted
    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n";
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n";

    while(cin>> data && data != 0)
    {
        arr.push_back(data);
        ++count;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    //display back data
    cout<<"The numbers enterd are: "<<endl;
    std:for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), print);
    cout<<endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler I have is 2010 so I used the second method but I am still getting an error on the arr.begin() and arr.end(). Does it have to do with storing arr as an int?

Comment: Ahhh, I see you are also using  `int *arr`, which is causing error  in 'arr. begin()' when compiling in C++ 98. I have updated code, so try again.

Comment: Thank you this worked. A few changes I made was changed `float data` to 'double data' and is just included the algorithm library. Other than that it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The given example code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float data;
    int count=0;
    int*arr=new int[count];

    //get amount of numbers inputted 
    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n";
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n";
    cin>>data;
    for (; data != 0 ; ++count)
    {
        cin>>data;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    //display back data
    cout<<"The numbers enterd are: "<<endl; 
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

… has many issues:

- Coding: using `float` for no reason.
  The default floating point type in C and C++ is `double`. E.g. the literal `3.14` is of type `double`, and any `float` value is promoted to `double` when passed to variadic C function. Only use `float` where a requirement is imposed by the context, e.g. a C API, or storing a zillion values in limited memory.
- Coding: using a raw array and a `new`-expression.
  The task is trivial when using `std::vector`. It's not a good idea to reinvent the wheel again and again. An exercise that requires you to reinvent `std::vector` or its most basic features should be very clear about that aspect: this isn't, so presumably reinvention is not required or what it's about.
- Design: signalling end-of-input via special value.
  That value can't be inputted.
- Coding: an input loop that doesn't store the numbers.
  Each number is stored in the same variable as the previous number, erasing the previous number. Store the numbers in a `std::vector`. E.g. you can use the `push_back` method.
- Coding: inconsistent convention for newline on output.
  Either use `endl`, or `"\n"`, as default. Don't mix them randomly. Consistency is very important because someone reading the code, who assumes a competent programmer, must treat every departure from the established defaults as being due to some *reason*. When there is no reason this wastes time and effort.
- Tool usage: the `system( "pause" )` is silly, counter-productive & non-portable.
  In Visual Studio, which it appears you're using, just run the program via **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>**. Or place a breakpoint on the last right brace of `main`, and run the program in the debugger via <kbd>F5</kbd>.
- Coding: the `return 0;` is superfluous.
  `main` is the only function that has a default return value. It has that in both C and C++. The default, 0 for success, is there to be used.

---

Example code with the above points, plus some, fixed.

This code is for C++11 or later so it **won't compile directly with Visual C++ 2010**.

I leave it as an exercise for you to translate it to C++03, which is what your current compiler can handle. Do consider upgrading. It's a free tool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>              // std::setw
#include <string>               // std::(string, stod)
#include <vector>               // std::vector
using namespace std;

using Half_float = float;                       // Most often a silly choice.
using Float = double;                           // Default in C++.
using Extended_float = long double;             // Same as double in Visual C++.

auto read_line()
    -> string
{ string line; getline( cin, line ); return line; }

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Please enter floating point numbers like " << 3.15 << ", one per line.\n";
    cout << "After the last number just press return again (i.e. a blank line).\n";

    vector<Float> numbers;
    for( ;; )
    {
        cout << "#" << numbers.size() + 1 << "? ";
        string const line = read_line();
        if( line.empty() )
        {
            break;
        }
        numbers.push_back( stod( line ) );      // Here you CAN do input validation.
    }

    cout << numbers.size() << " numbers entered.\n";
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "The numbers entered were: \n";
    for( int i = 0; i < int( numbers.size() ); ++i )
    {
        cout << setw( 3 ) << i << ": " << numbers[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The code will access out-of-bounds of `arr`, which has zero elements, unless you enter `0` for the first prompt.
- You didn't assign what you read to "elements or `arr`" (actually there will be no elements in `arr`) at all.
- There will be no reason why you should use array of `int` to store `float` data.

You should use `std::vector`, which works as variable-size array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float data;
    int count=0;
    vector<float> arr;

    //get amount of numbers inputted 
    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n";
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n";
    while(cin >> data && data != 0)
    {
        arr.push_back(data);
    }
    count = arr.size();
    cout<<count<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    //display back data
    cout<<"The numbers enterd are: "<<endl; 
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is using a std::vector the only way to go? I've never used that before and I really don't won't use something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Of course not. You can use a linked list, or allocate new array and copy contents of old array when the old array is filled with data and more data have to be stored.